# Maven jetty or tomcat plugin with hot deploy option including dependencies

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, dependencies, jetty, redeploy

I have a maven project with root module called "sample" and two child modules in their own directories "sample-services" and "sample-web". "sample-web" is a war module which depends on "sample-services"

I want to be able to run my server from maven (it could be jetty, tomcat, or any lightweight server) and debug my code without using eclipse or intellij idea j2ee integration (for example in Intellij Idea community edition or other IDE that supports remote debugger) and just by adding a remote debugger.

I could start my app with "jetty:run" and attach the debugger but the problem is that when I change my code in "sample-services" it doesn't pick it up unless I run "mvn install" on that module separately and restart the server.

Is there a better way to be able to debug the app and have the server redeploy the code changes without having to restart the server?
I know eclipse can do this for a maven project. It will detect the changes in dependent project and upload them to the server.

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>9.0.3.v20130506</version>
        </plugin>
```

**EDIT**:

I ended up using tomcat maven plugin for now:
            
                org.apache.tomcat.maven
                tomcat7-maven-plugin
                2.1
                
                    /
                    true
                
            
in your pom.xml and run in the command line: mvn tomcat7:run
Downside is that this will reload the whole app upon each change instead of hot-deploy.

So now I am looking for a hot deploy alternative.

Comment: Perhaps you can do this with JRebel.

Comment: JRebel is not free. I need an open source or free solution.